# load external xml

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

i have the next code in an ASP page, but i would like to retrieve an external xml file. Does anyone know how can I do it?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<%
'Load XML
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = false
xml.load(Server.MapPath("resp2.xml"))

'Load XSL
set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xsl.async = false
xsl.load(Server.MapPath("resp.xsl"))

'Transform file
Response.Write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
%>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "external" files? Uploaded dynamically/on-the-fly?

Comment: over what medium? file share? http request? etc.

Comment: It should have to use http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
'Load XML
set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.load("http://yourdomain.com/resp2.xml")
```

Comment: what about if the file is an ASP type and is in a local server?

Comment: An asp file can output xml just as easily as it can output html, and you can use any URL which your server can see - so as long as http ://localhost/myfile.asp outputs valid XML it should work fine

Comment: that is what I m doing, but if I call the file directly as myfile.asp I get an error in the server, the same way if I call the file as http://localhost/myfile.asp . Otherwise if I type the URL as http://mydomain.com/myfile.asp it works.

Comment: my asp file outputs a XML file, but the problem is that this file is protected and if I access it from mydomain.com/myfile.asp I loose the credentials. So I need to access this file using an internal way.

Comment: I suppose you could use Scripting.FileSystemObject to write an xml file to your server and then use that as your source - it wouldn't need the server to make an http request.  What do you mean by "your credentials"  If you mean session variables they they will be lost because it's a different session, it's the server accessing the serverhttprequest url, not your own browser.  You could always send them to myfile.asp in a querystring

Answer (score 1):

Try use ServerXMLHTTP object:

```
Dim xmlReq, sResponse
Set xmlReq = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
Call xmlReq.open("GET", "http://host/dir/page.xml")
Call xmlReq.send()
If (xmlReq.status = 200) Then
    sResponse = xmlReq.responseText

End If
```

Comment: hello, when using your code I get an error saying: "Object does not support this property or method: 'TransformNode'"

Comment: Code above only for getting data from external resource. After You recieve content in sResponse variable, pass them into Your code like `code`xml.loadXML(sResponse)`code`